# Husqvarna leaf blower problem

Tags: tools, repair, tool-maintenance, small-engine

I put new carburetor, fuel line, filter, and plug, and it is still not running right. The model is 125v.

Listen to the [video](https://youtu.be/JOWy6WD3uWY). It sounds like it is missing.

Comment: it really does sound like it isn't getting enough fuel. Or too much fuel. Or water in the fuel. Is there an adjustment screw on the carb? Is the choke stuck?

Comment: I also replaced the fuel and am using non-ethanol fuel.  I replaced the fuel line as well

Comment: It sounds similar to a chain saw where the spark arrestor is getting plugged. How about the air intake and filter, possible to clean?

Comment: It has a brand new air filter that came with the carb kit so that can't be the problem.